# depuración react login google

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Antes que nada soy un novato con react así que disculpas por lo básico de la consulta, tengo un proyecto que muestra datos de empleados y departamentos mediante una api y estoy intentando insertar un login de google dentro de App.js, el problema me surge al no saber como estructurar las variables, lo que me da un error de compilación ya que no se como emplear hooks dentro de una clase. Lo que necesito es que pinte por pantalla el nombre, el mail y la foto de la persona que se loguea. Gracias por la ayuda!

App.js

```
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Home } from './components/Home';
import { Department } from './components/Department';
import { Employee } from './components/Employee';
import { Navigation } from './components/Navigation';
import GoogleLogin from 'react-google-login';


export default class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [url, setUrl] = useState("");

    const responseGoogle = (response) => {
      setName(response.profileObj.name);
      setEmail(response.profileObj.email);
      setUrl(response.profileObj.imageUrl);
    };

  }

  render () {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
          <div className="container">
              <div className="float-right"><GoogleLogin //Botón Google
                  clientId="128507741231-f29fn3id10e5nhoihsdsgrr8t44r4.apps.googleusercontent.com"
                  buttonText="Login"
                  onSuccess={responseGoogle}
                  onFailure={responseGoogle}
                  cookiePolicy={'single_host_origin'}
              /></div>
              <h3 className="m-3 d-flex justify-content-center">
                      MI API
              </h3>
              <p>Nombre: {name} </p>       //NOMBRE
              <p>Correo: { email}</p>         //EMAIL
              <img src={url} alt={name}/>       //FOTO
              <Navigation />
              <Switch>
                  <Route path="/" component={Home} exact />
                  <Route path="/department" component={Department} exact />
                  <Route path="/employee" component={Employee} exact />
               </Switch>
          </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Tengo entendido que los `hooks` se aplican sólo a componentes funcionales, no componentes de clase :(

Comment: los debes usar en funciones, no clases como se ve en el código, el caso es que no se como hacer para realizar lo que necesito...

Comment: Revisa [este link](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html), el cambio no es tan grande :D